# Conda says conflict over installing dateutil in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, python-dateutil

I have a Python 3.5.1 environment managed by conda. I'm trying to create a new Python 3.5.1 environment with `conda create` and listing several of the modules I want in the new environment.

One such module is [`dateutil`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/dateutil) (*not* `python-dateutil`), which is already installed for the existing 3.5.1 environment and was installed merely with the command `conda install dateutil` -- which gave no warnings or conflicts when I created that environment around 6 months ago. I'm trying to replicate this environment to provide something cloneable to share for an analysis with a collaborator -- when I use `conda list` on my current 3.5.1 environment, I see that plain `dateutil` is installed, not `python-dateutil`, so that's what I need.

However, now when I try to include `dateutil` for the new environment, it says there is a conflict and that `dateutil` is only available for Python 2.6.*, 2.7.*, 3.3.*, 3.4.*.

Here's an example:

```
user@computer:~/programming$ conda create -n test_dateutil python=3.5.1 dateutil
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ............
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - dateutil -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*
  - python 3.5.1*
```

But with the existing Python 3.5.1 environment, `dateutil` is clearly installed with no trouble:

```
(py35)user@computer:~$ ipython
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: dateutil
Out[1]: <module 'dateutil' from '/home/user/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.py'>

In [2]: dateutil.
dateutil.easter         dateutil.relativedelta  dateutil.tz             
dateutil.parser         dateutil.rrule          

In [2]: dateutil.__
dateutil.__builtins__  dateutil.__file__      dateutil.__package__   dateutil.__version__
dateutil.__cached__    dateutil.__loader__    dateutil.__path__      
dateutil.__doc__       dateutil.__name__      dateutil.__spec__      

In [2]: dateutil.__version__
Out[2]: '2.4.2'

In [3]: dateutil.__package__
Out[3]: 'dateutil'
```

From `conda list`

```
    (py35)user@computer:~$ conda list
    # packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda/envs/py35:
    #
    cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/cycler-0.10.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    cython                    0.24                     py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/cython-0.24-py35_0.tar.bz2
    dateutil                  2.4.2                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/dateutil-2.4.2-py35_0.tar.bz2
    decorator                 4.0.2                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/decorator-4.0.2-py35_0.tar.bz2
    entrypoints               0.2                      py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/entrypoints-0.2-py35_1.tar.bz2
    fontconfig                2.11.1                        5    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/fontconfig-2.11.1-5.tar.bz2
    freetype                  2.5.5                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/freetype-2.5.5-0.tar.bz2
    funcsigs                  0.4                      py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/funcsigs-0.4-py35_0.tar.bz2
    ipykernel                 4.3.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ipykernel-4.3.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    ipython                   4.1.2                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ipython-4.1.2-py35_0.tar.bz2
    ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
    ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ipython_genutils-0.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    ipywidgets                4.1.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ipywidgets-4.1.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    jinja2                    2.8                      py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jinja2-2.8-py35_1.tar.bz2
    jsonschema                2.5.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jsonschema-2.5.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jupyter-1.0.0-py35_3.tar.bz2
    jupyter-client            4.2.2                     <pip>
    jupyter-console           4.1.1                     <pip>
    jupyter-core              4.1.0                     <pip>
    jupyter_client            4.2.2                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jupyter_client-4.2.2-py35_0.tar.bz2
    jupyter_console           4.1.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jupyter_console-4.1.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    jupyter_core              4.1.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/jupyter_core-4.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    libgfortran               3.0                           0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/libgfortran-3.0-0.tar.bz2
    libpng                    1.6.17                        0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/libpng-1.6.17-0.tar.bz2
    libsodium                 1.0.10                        0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/libsodium-1.0.10-0.tar.bz2
    libxml2                   2.9.2                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/libxml2-2.9.2-0.tar.bz2
    markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/markupsafe-0.23-py35_2.tar.bz2
    matplotlib                1.5.1               np110py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/matplotlib-1.5.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2
    midiutil                  HEAD                      <pip>
    mistune                   0.7.2                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/mistune-0.7.2-py35_0.tar.bz2
    mkl                       11.3.1                        0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/mkl-11.3.1-0.tar.bz2
    mock                      1.3.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/mock-1.3.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/nbconvert-4.2.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    nbformat                  4.0.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/nbformat-4.0.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    ncurses                   5.9                           5    https://conda.binstar.org/asmeurer/linux-64/ncurses-5.9-5.tar.bz2
    nose                      1.3.7                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/nose-1.3.7-py35_0.tar.bz2
    notebook                  4.2.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/notebook-4.2.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    numpy                     1.10.4                   py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/numpy-1.10.4-py35_1.tar.bz2
    openblas                  0.2.14                        4    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/openblas-0.2.14-4.tar.bz2
    openssl                   1.0.2d                        0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/openssl-1.0.2d-0.tar.bz2
    pandas                    0.16.2              np110py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pandas-0.16.2-np110py35_0.tar.bz2
    path.py                   7.6.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/path.py-7.6.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    patsy                     0.4.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/patsy-0.4.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pbr                       1.3.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pbr-1.3.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pexpect                   3.3                      py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pexpect-3.3-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pickleshare               0.5                      py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pickleshare-0.5-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pip                       7.1.2                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pip-7.1.2-py35_0.tar.bz2
    psycopg2                  2.6.1                    py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/psycopg2-2.6.1-py35_1.tar.bz2
    ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ptyprocess-0.5.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pygments                  2.1.3                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pygments-2.1.3-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pyparsing-2.0.3-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pyqt-4.11.4-py35_1.tar.bz2
    pystan                    2.8.0.0                  py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pystan-2.8.0.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    python                    3.5.1                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/python-3.5.1-0.tar.bz2
    pytz                      2015.4                   py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pytz-2015.4-py35_0.tar.bz2
    pyyaml                    3.11                     py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pyyaml-3.11-py35_1.tar.bz2
    pyzmq                     15.2.0                   py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/pyzmq-15.2.0-py35_1.tar.bz2
    qt                        4.8.7                         1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/qt-4.8.7-1.tar.bz2
    qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/qtconsole-4.2.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    readline                  6.2.5                         1    https://conda.binstar.org/asmeurer/linux-64/readline-6.2.5-1.tar.bz2
    runcython3                0.2.6                     <pip>
    scikit-learn              0.16.1              np110py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/scikit-learn-0.16.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2
    scipy                     0.17.0              np110py35_2    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/scipy-0.17.0-np110py35_2.tar.bz2
    seaborn                   0.7.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/seaborn-0.7.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    setuptools                18.1                     py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/setuptools-18.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/simplegeneric-0.8.1-py35_0.tar.bz2
    sip                       4.16.9                   py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/sip-4.16.9-py35_0.tar.bz2
    six                       1.9.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/six-1.9.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    sqlalchemy                1.0.12                   py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/sqlalchemy-1.0.12-py35_0.tar.bz2
    sqlite                    3.8.4.1                       1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/sqlite-3.8.4.1-1.tar.bz2
    statsmodels               0.6.1               np110py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/statsmodels-0.6.1-np110py35_0.tar.bz2
    terminado                 0.6                      py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/terminado-0.6-py35_0.tar.bz2
    tk                        8.5.18                        0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/tk-8.5.18-0.tar.bz2
    tornado                   4.3                      py35_1    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/tornado-4.3-py35_1.tar.bz2
    traitlets                 4.0.0                    py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/traitlets-4.0.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    wheel                     0.24.0                   py35_0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/wheel-0.24.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
    xz                        5.0.5                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/xz-5.0.5-0.tar.bz2
    yaml                      0.1.6                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/yaml-0.1.6-0.tar.bz2
    zeromq                    4.1.4                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/zeromq-4.1.4-0.tar.bz2
    zlib                      1.2.8                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/zlib-1.2.8-0.tar.bz2
```

The particular tarball for `dateutil` doesn't appear to exist anymore (but definitely was installed with just a simple `conda install dateutil` previously).

Comment: What does `pip install dateutil` say?

Comment: This needs to specifically be managed by conda (and not Anaconda's pip either). The package exists, just lists a conflict about versions that seemingly did not exist 6 months ago.

Comment: Does `conda` use a different nomenclature for dateutil? The pip package is called `python-dateutil`.

Comment: As far as I know conda recognizes packages that were installed with pip. Why does it have to be conda?

Comment: @Paul I am referring to just the [dateutil package](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/dateutil). Anaconda.org also has python-dateutil, but in my case in my older 3.5.1 environment, when I use conda list to see what's in that environment, it is the plain `dateutil` package and not the `python-dateutil` package. I am trying to replicate the libraries from that older environment, so whatever is in `dateutil` that's what I need -- even though it looks like `python-dateutil` is what should be preferred for new environments that don't have to replicate old environments as mine does in this case.

Answer (score 13):

The related Github issue said that the `dateutil` package was renamed as `python-dateutil`.

Thus, a mere `conda install python-dateutil` works fine with Python 3.5.

Comment: see above comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776256/conda-says-conflict-over-installing-dateutil-in-python-3-5-1/41099466#comment63021249_37776256

Answer (score 1):

The URL http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/dateutil-2.4.2-py35_0.tar.bz2 no longer exists, and I'm not sure why.  I'm filing an issue for you on anaconda-issues.

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/858